# Function to find values in matrix by corresponding hum. and temperatures in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, find, tidyverse

I have the following matrix and I need to use some R function to find the value in the table correspondent to temperatures in the cols (in Celsius) and with humidity in the rows (%):

[image: matrix temp x humidity]

[(*Link for the image here)](https://github.com/rhozon/datasets/raw/master/matrix_temp_hum.png)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

url <-'https://github.com/rhozon/datasets/raw/master/Matrix_HumxTemps.xlsx'
matrixtemp <- tempfile()
download.file(url, matrixtemp, mode="wb")
matrix.temp.hum <- read_excel(path = matrixtemp, sheet = 1)

glimpse(matrix.temp.hum)

Rows: 21
Columns: 36
$ ...1         <chr> "Hum. (%)", "14", "15", "16", "17", "17.5", "18", "19", "…
$ `Temp. (°C)` <dbl> 1.70000, 2733.33333, 2200.00000, 1666.66667, 1133.33333, …
$ ...3         <dbl> 2.00000, 2608.33333, 2100.00000, 1591.66667, 1083.33333, …
$ ...4         <dbl> 3.00000, 2483.33333, 2000.00000, 1516.66667, 1033.33333, …
$ ...5         <dbl> 4.00000, 2358.33333, 1900.00000, 1441.66667, 983.33333, 5…
$ ...6         <dbl> 5.00000, 2233.33333, 1800.00000, 1366.66667, 933.33333, 5…
$ ...7         <dbl> 6.00000, 2116.66667, 1700.00000, 1283.33333, 866.66667, 4…
```

How can I use some R function that can return to me the value correspondent to 14 hum. and 25 temp. ?

Comment: Have you considered perhaps saving your excel sheet as a `csv` and then reading it?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

```r
HUM <- 3; TEMP <- "17"
dplyr::filter(fakedata, hum == HUM) %>%
  select(one_of(TEMP))
#   17
# 1 11
```

and reshaping/pivoting the data:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(fakedata, -hum, names_to = "temp") %>%
  filter(hum == HUM, temp == TEMP)
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#     hum temp  value
#   <int> <chr> <int>
# 1     3 17       11
```

The latter has the advantage that if you need to interpolate (i.e., the temperature you need is not explicitly matched), then it becomes simpler:

```r
HUM <- 3; TEMP <- 17.5 # this temp is not present
pivot_longer(fakedata, -hum, names_to = "temp") %>%
  mutate(temp = as.numeric(temp)) %>%
  filter(hum == HUM) %>%
  summarize(setNames(data.frame(
    approx(temp, value, xout = TEMP)),
    c("temp", "value"))
  )
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#    temp value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  17.5  12.3
```

or if you are confident that a simple regression can map the two variables to your value, then

```r
pivot_longer(fakedata, -hum, names_to = "temp") %>%
  mutate(temp = as.numeric(temp)) %>%
  summarize(data.frame(
    value = predict(lm(value ~ hum + temp, data = cur_data()), newdata = data.frame(hum=HUM, temp=TEMP))
  ))
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#   value
#   <dbl>
# 1  12.5
```

---

Data

```r
fakedata <- data.frame(matrix(1:20, nrow = 4))
colnames(fakedata) <- c("hum", "16", "17", "18.5", "19")
fakedata
#   hum 16 17 18.5 19
# 1   1  5  9   13 17
# 2   2  6 10   14 18
# 3   3  7 11   15 19
# 4   4  8 12   16 20
```

Comment: I think it works if I can solve how to read first correctly the .xlsx using matrix perspective by rows (hum) and cols (temp)... How did you suggest @r2evans ?

Comment: From the image of your data, it looks like you should be using `readxl::read_excel(path=matrixtemp, sheet=1, skip=1)` (add `skip=`).